# Unable to create another box in a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap Code: http://www.bootply.com/rKAlUVLSTA

I'm trying to create a box below the left sidebar but whatever I do, it is always in the white background zone. I do understand that if i add the "leftbar" class elsewhere, it will work but the width has to remain same as the logo background.

Screenshot:

[image: Box]

Comment: Please put any relevant code in the question. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: What Marcelo means is the code that you use for creating the sidebar, you can add code with your question

Comment: I thought it's better to put it in the third party website as it compiles the code too. Next Time. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution: http://www.bootply.com/rw2brhxWy7 Basically what you had to do is split up the two into two separate columns within a parent column. I added a `margin-top: 20px` to be able to distinguish the two.

Relevant code below:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="col-md-12 leftbar" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
        </div><!--/.navbar-header -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
        <div class="text-center">
          <p>John Doe</p>
          <p>Points</p>
        </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav sidebar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Innovation</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Redeem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 leftbar" style="margin-top: 20px;">

      I want to free myself from this white box and be in a new box instead.<p></p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edit:** The problem was that now the column did not match the width of the green navbar div. You must remember that bootstrap's CSS will apply a padding of 20px left & right to every column. In order to fix this you should add a custom class to override that. Add the following class:

```
.noPadding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Add this class to the following div:

```
<div class="col-md-2 noPadding">
    <div class="col-md-12 leftbar" style="margin-top:50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 leftbar" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edited Solution Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/tLCcdki4uP

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the answer, this helps prevent link rot and maintain the answer quality in the future.

Comment: Please just comment and I will do so,

Comment: Thank You very much @VladBardalez. However, the width (check the logo width) has decrease as you can see. This was the problem :(

Comment: @VladBardalez it's not working. this was exactly what i had earlier :(

Comment: @ElaineByene Please see edit. Add a custom CSS class to override Bootstrap's CSS